# Angularjs conditional templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have got following code in an Angular directive:

```
for(var key in navData) {

   if ('/'+key === newValue) {

          var str = "<ul>";

          for( var i=0; i < navData[key].length; i++ ) {

              str = str + "<li><a href='urlVal'> titleVal </a></li>";
              str = str.replace("urlVal", navData[key][i].url);
              str = str.replace("titleVal", navData[key][i].title);

          }
        str = str + "</ul>";
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Above code works fine but I would like to improve this. Is there any way I can take this conditional string building in external template?

Comment: What is the purpose of your directive ? Is it to display this string based on navData and newValue parameters ?

Comment: navValue is url, so based on url I want to select menu.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle / plunker with your implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` will be available in the next major stable release, 1.2. The release should be available some time this summer but an exact date hasn't been announced yet. If you can't wait, you always have the option to switch to the current unstable release 1.1.5. While the name "unstable" might look scary, "unstable" is used for 1.1 branch simply because all of the new features going to be introduced in 1.2 are added to it and thus could potentially have more bugs. Having that said, all new features in 1.1.5 are fully covered by test cases. Indeed, I have been enjoying 1.1.5 for my current project under development and no problem so far.

FYI. When the time arrives to release 1.2, the latest version from the 1.1 branch then will simply be renamed to 1.2, and 1.1.5 is a likely choice.